# Помогите найти ошибку в коде Увеличение и уменьшение значения в поле input

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку в коде "Увеличение и уменьшение значения в поле input".почему у меня при нажатии на плюс или минус идет увелич\умень на 2 единицы. когда проверил работу кода в инспекторе - получается что выполняется код до return, а затем вместо завершения работы функции повторно выполняется весь код и уже потом return. код скопирован с сайта http://pcvector.net на котором демо нормально работает.

```
<span class="counter__link counter__link_prev"></span>
          <input type="text" class="qwnt" value="{{ item.quantity }}"  
   price="{{ item.sale_price }}" name="cart[quantity][{{ item.id }}]" 
   size="3" maxlength="4" autocomplete="off">
          <span class="counter__link counter__link_next"></span>

<script type="text/jаvascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.counter__link_prev').click(function () {
            var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
            var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
            count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
            $input.val(count);
            $input.change();
            return false;
        });
        $('.counter__link_next').click(function () {
            var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
            $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
            $input.change();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JvLaZN - чисто ваш код. Добавляется/уменьшается по одному

Comment: Спасибо. а что может влиять на работу кода что на сайте он работает криво

Comment: может вы 2 раза подключаете скрипт/ вешаете обработчик?

Comment: Да, получается что дважды вешаю. спасибо большое. буду разбираться

Comment: Не могу понять почему обработчик вешается дважды. Циклов нет. Подскажите как выловить

Comment: https://codepen.io/kirilldonenko/pen/QrmZVd здесь только JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот рабочий вариант с вашим кодом:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.counter__link_prev').click(function () {
            var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
            var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
            count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
            $input.val(count);
            $input.change();
            return false;
        });
        $('.counter__link_next').click(function () {
            var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
            $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
            $input.change();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

```css
input {
  width: 50px;
}

span {
  user-select: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="counter__link counter__link_prev">-</span>
          
          <input type="text" class="qwnt" value="1"  
   price="{{ item.sale_price }}" name="cart[quantity][{{ item.id }}]" 
   size="3" maxlength="4" autocomplete="off">
          
          <span class="counter__link counter__link_next">+</span>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. код работает но какого черта у меня вешается ещё один обработчик тем же кодом, в той же строке

Comment: Можно ваш код? Или это весь код?

Comment: Я знаю, поставьте `debugger;`

Comment: codepen.io/kirilldonenko/pen/QrmZVd здесь только JS

Comment: добавил скрин после нажатия на "-". count должен быть 15 по-моему

Comment: Там главное скажи, после нажатия один раз отработал дебаггер или 2?

Comment: два раза. дошел до return и выполнил код ещё раз

Comment: Значит нет сомнений код выполняется 2 раза.

Comment: да. я вверху скрин вставлял. на нем видно что на кнопках висит по два onclick - вопрос почему и как ставиться второй

Comment: А поставьте ка дебагер в самом начале где $(document).ready() внутри

Comment: просто остановился на дебагере перед кодом

Comment: Ну debugger 2 раза отработал?

Comment: да, два раза отработал

Comment: Тогда ошибка решена, у тебя подключаются скрипты 2 раза. Cмотри где и удаляй одно подключение :)

Comment: СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ

Comment: Обращайся :) и чаще пользуйся `debugger;` ))

Comment: Понял. Спасибо, сам бы не додумался о втором подключении

Comment: Обращайся если что :)